# Forward traffic to other interface

Tags: networking, iptables, forwarding, tap

I have two interfaces eth0 and eth1. I want all traffic on eth0 to be forwarded to eth1 without changing anything to packet(origin Src/Dst IP, port etc. has to same).
[image]
I found some articles about forwarding but they were using NAT to relay traffics something like this.

```
sudo iptables -F FORWARD
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Is there any way to forward traffics without doing NAT?

Comment: You should probably do bridging instead of routing. Either way, iptables has not much to do with this. iptables might affect routing, but it's not doing routing itself.

Comment: Thanks A.B! Informations I searched were using iptables so I thought iptables could do this. Is there any options to do routing or bridging in linux?

Comment: Oh I think I found something. I will try to solve this problem using bridge-utils. Thanks

Comment: leave your answer here later then!

Comment: Thanks A.B! Have a nice day :)